# ACS Appcelerator iOS not receiving push

Tags: ios, titanium, push, appcelerator, acs

I'm currently trying to make push notification working for dev/production environment through Appcelerator Platform.
I created my push certificates (dev/prod) on apple developer platform, I exported it to .p12 file, and uploaded it on my ArrowDB iOS Push configuration. My Titanium app and my ArrowDB seems correctly linked (good keys for production and developpement).

From my app, I get device token, I get a successfull return from subscribing to notifications, and I can see from Appcelerator that I have one ios device linked.

When I send push notification from Appcelerator ArrowDB platform, I don't receive anything while Appcelerator logs shows a Successful push.

My code for ACS Notification handling :

```
var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');

var ANDROID = Ti.Platform.name === 'android';
var IOS = !ANDROID && (Ti.Platform.name === 'iPhone OS');
var BLACKBERRY = !ANDROID && !IOS && (Ti.Platform.name === 'blackberry');
Cloud.debug = true;  // optional; if you add this line, set it to false for production

var deviceToken = null;

// Check if the device is running iOS 8 or later
if (Ti.Platform.name == "iPhone OS" && parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 8) {

    // Wait for user settings to be registered before registering for push notifications
    Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('usernotificationsettings', function registerForPush() {

        // Remove event listener once registered for push notifications
        Ti.App.iOS.removeEventListener('usernotificationsettings', registerForPush); 

        Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
            success: deviceTokenSuccess,
            error: deviceTokenError,
            callback: receivePush
        });
    });

    // Register notification types to use
    Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings({
        types: [
            Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
            Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND,
            Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE
        ]
    });
}

// For iOS 7 and earlier
else {

    Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
        // Specifies which notifications to receive
        types: [
            Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
            Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
            Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
        ],
        success: deviceTokenSuccess,
        error: deviceTokenError,
        callback: receivePush
    });
}

// Process incoming push notifications
function receivePush(e) {
    console.log('Received push: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
    alert('Received push: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
}
// Save the device token for subsequent API calls
function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
    deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
}

function deviceTokenError(e) {
    alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
}



function ACSPush(acsuid, acspwd) {
    this.acsuid = acsuid || false;
    this.acspwd = acspwd || false;
}

ACSPush.prototype.registerDevice = function(channel_name, onReceive, onLaunched, onFocused, androidOptions, iosOptions, blackberryOptions) {
    var that = this,
        token = '';

    function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
        console.log('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
        token = e.deviceToken;
        that.token = token;
        loginToACS(that.acsuid, that.acspwd, token, channel_name);
    }

    function deviceTokenError(e) {
        console.log('Token Error: ' + e.error);
    }

    function receivePush(e) {
        onReceive(e.data);
        console.log("push notification received: " + JSON.stringify(e.data));
    }

    if (ANDROID) {
        var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
        CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
            success : deviceTokenSuccess,
            error : deviceTokenError
        });

        CloudPush.focusAppOnPush = androidOptions.focusAppOnPush || false;
        CloudPush.showAppOnTrayClick = androidOptions.showAppOnTrayClick || false;
        CloudPush.showTrayNotification = androidOptions.showTrayNotification || false;
        CloudPush.showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused = androidOptions.showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused || false;
        CloudPush.singleCallback = androidOptions.singleCallback || true;
        CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', onReceive);
        CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', onLaunched);
        CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', onFocused);

    } else if (IOS) {
        // Check if the device is running iOS 8 or later
        if (parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 8) {
            function registerForPush() {
                Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
                    success : deviceTokenSuccess,
                    error : deviceTokenError,
                    callback : receivePush
                });
                // Remove event listener once registered for push notifications
                Ti.App.iOS.removeEventListener('usernotificationsettings', registerForPush);
            };

            // Wait for user settings to be registered before registering for push notifications
            Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('usernotificationsettings', registerForPush);

            // Register notification types to use
            Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings({
                types : iosOptions.types,
                categories : iosOptions.categories
            });

        } else {
            // For iOS 7 and earlier
            Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
                // Specifies which notifications to receive
                types : iosOptions.types,
                success : deviceTokenSuccess,
                error : deviceTokenError,
                callback : receivePush
            });
        }

    } else if (BLACKBERRY) {
        Ti.BlackBerry.createPushService({
            appId : blackberryOptions.appId,
            ppgUrl : blackberryOptions.ppgUrl,
            usePublicPpg : blackberryOptions.usePublicPpg,
            launchApplicationOnPush : blackberryOptions.launchApplicationOnPush,
            onSessionCreated : function(e) {
                console.log('Session Created');
            },
            onChannelCreated : function(e) {
                console.log('Channel Created\nMessage: ' + e.message + '\nToken: ' + e.token);
                token = e.token;
                that.token = token;
                console.log("Device Token: " + token);
                loginToACS(that.acsuid, that.acspwd, token, channel_name);
            },
            onPushReceived : function(e) {
                onReceive(e.data);
                e.source.removeAllPushes();
            },
            onConfigError : function(e) {
                console.log('ERROR\nTitle: ' + e.errorTitle + +'\nMsg: ' + e.errorMessage);
            },
            onError : function(e) {
                console.log('ERROR\nTitle: ' + e.errorTitle + +'\nMsg: ' + e.errorMessage);
            },
            onAppOpened : function(e) {
                onLaunched(e.data);

                e.source.removePush(e.pushId);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Push notification not implemented yet into acspushmod for " + Ti.Platform.osname);
    }
};

ACSPush.prototype.unsubscribeFromChannel = function(channel_name, token, onSuccess, onFail) {

    var that = this;
    Cloud.PushNotifications.unsubscribe({
        channel : channel_name,
        device_token : token
    }, function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            onSuccess(e);
        } else {
            onFail(e);
        }
    });
};

ACSPush.prototype.getToken = function() {
    return this.token;
};
function loginToACS(acsuid, acspwd, token, channel_name) {
    if (!acsuid && !acspwd) {
        console.log("loginToACS -> subscribe as guest");
        subscribeForPushNotifications(token, channel_name, true);
        return;
    }
    Cloud.Users.login({
        login : acsuid,
        password : acspwd
    }, function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            var user = e.users[0];
            console.log("loginToACS -> Status: Successful");
            subscribeForPushNotifications(token, channel_name);
        } else {
                console.log('acsuid = ' + acsuid + " acspwd = " + acspwd);
            console.log("loginToACS -> Error :" + e.message);
        }
    });
};

function subscribeForPushNotifications(token, channel_name, subscribeAsGuest) {
    var prams = {
        channel : channel_name,
        type : IOS ? 'ios' : Ti.Platform.osname, // osname return iphone / ipad on iOS
        device_token : token
    };
    var callBack = function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            console.log('subscribeForPushNotifications -> Status: Successful [' + channel_name + ']');
        } else {
            console.log('subscribeForPushNotifications -> Error ' + token + '(subscribeToServerPush) :\\n' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    };
    if (subscribeAsGuest) {
        Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribeToken(prams, callBack);
    } else {
        Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe(prams, callBack);
    }
};
```

And This code used to work before I change appcelerator account (migrating to my client account).

If you guys have any idea of what am I doing wrong, I will be very thankful.

Thanks a lot !

Environment : Appcelerator studio, Titanium SDK 5.0.0.GA, iphone5S

Comment: I had a similar issue before. I regenerated a new provisioning profile and used it to deploy the app. Then I received the notifications. Not sure if it helps in your situation.

Comment: I see you are calling methods like `registerUserNotificationSettings` at two places in your code. Maybe it would be good to do a build of the same app where you replace the app (or at least this part of it) with the example code from http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Subscribing_to_push_notifications to rule out any bugs in that. Then you know what to focus on.